# Linux I/O issue? Multiple FFMPEG saving streams as HLS, lose segments despite low CPU and Memory consumption

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, aws, amazon-ec2, streaming

I'm capturing an RTMP stream as HLS (saving playlist files) using FFMPEG wihout any stream processing, merely copying it.
Thanks to such setup I'm able to run tens of processes (I've tried 80 at most), with memory and CPU consumption not exceeding 30%.

This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i <RTMP__STREAM_URL> -hls_init_time 10 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -strftime 1 -hls_segment_filename '%H-%M-%S-%s.ts' -hls_flags split_by_time -codec:v copy -codec:a copy ./play$(date -d "today" +"%M%S-%s").m3u8
```

Unfortunately, as the number of processes grows, I start losing some HLS segments (HLS consists of a playlist file, and segments composing that file).
For example the HLS plays fine from 0:00 until 0:40, but then freezes at 0:40 for 10s (my segments are 10s long) and unfreezes at 0:50.

With 20 FFMPEG processes running, the loss rate is about 5%, at  80 processes its close to 50%.

I'm performing those benchmarks at AWS EC2 instances using Ubuntu 22.x, and various machine types. No matter the machine type, the error's frequency remains the same, thus I assume it's not CPU or Memory related.

I suspect that's something related to I/O and file writes, either an EC2 or Ubuntu setup.

Any ideas?

Comment: what's the buffering you use, and how much network bandwidth are you using? Is this all from the same streaming server? It's not unheard of for streaming servers to limit the throughput to a single client / IP address, especially in the cloud (try binding to different IPv6 addresses, AWS should give you thousands per instance)

Comment: Add `delayacct` to kernel boot flags and reboot, run `sudo iotop` and check stats.

Comment: I've fixed it!
@MarcusMüller Thank you! I've started to test the bandwith case and run 20 processes with 4 different streams. As I kept playing those afterwards it turned out that streams are overlapping (the frozen fragment would contain a frame from a different stream). That made me realise that some streams overwrite each other's files. After adding a RAND value to each playlist's TS files, the issue disappeared.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Ubuntu boot flags can't be changed with Grubby at EC2, so I've decided to check without the flag first and it shown around 5MB/s. Before I proceeded to changing the flags I managed to find the solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Here's the final command
ffmpeg -i <RTMP_STREAM_URL> -hls_init_time 10 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -strftime 1 -hls_segment_filename $(rand)'%H-%M-%S-%s.ts' -hls_flags split_by_time -codec:v copy -codec:a copy play$(date -d "today" +"%M%S-%s").m3u8 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &

Comment: @Yyyeey cool! Glad you fixed it! Could you put *how* you fixed it in the answer field below? That way, a future reader will easily see that there's a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Turns out that had nothing to do with resources or any sort of performance. The videos were freezing because the processes had been overwriting each other's segments.

Apparently timestamps with milliseconds precision were not unique enough. I've fixed it by adding a randomly generated value to each process, which then was used in the file names.
Ofc. the same would be achieved if I used a different directory for each process, etc.

Here's the command working perfectly even with 100 processes:

```
ffmpeg -i <RTMP_STREAM_URL> -hls_init_time 10 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -strftime 1 -hls_segment_filename $(rand)'%H-%M-%S-%s.ts' -hls_flags split_by_time -codec:v copy -codec:a copy play_$(rand)_$(date -d "today" +"%M%S-%s").m3u8 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```